# Many Datacontract in wcf

Tags: wcf

I'm a newbie in the VS world, all my background is based in JAVA and for the time being I'm working on a WCF service, just want to know if I have the chance to create different `[DataContract]` in different .cs files(ex: a class for Person, a class for Department, etc...) and if the class that implements those `DataContract`(that are specified in different .cs files) will recognize them just for the fact that I specified the `DataContract` attribute.

As I wrote at the very beginning, I'm a newbie so any suggestions would be very welcome

Comment: Well, yes, you need to decorate each class with `[DataContract]` and serializable properties with `[DataMember]` (or note that without these attributes, `DataContractSerializer` will default to serializing just the public properties). Is there a more specific question?

Answer (score 0):

> if I have the chance to create differents [DataContract] in differents .cs files(ex: a class for Person, a class for Department, etc...) and if the class that implements those Datacontract(that are specified in different .cs files)...

Unlike c++, in c# you do not declare and then define a class - it is all done in one step, usually one class per file.

> will reconigze them just for the fact that I specified the DataContract attribute

Yes